# Fractal-like shapes - is there a name for these?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, art

So I created some geometric art inspired by string art. I feel like there's a name for this type of shape/image. I'm asking on mathematics.stackexchange because the process of generating the below images is very mathematical. To produce one of the shape in the $i^{th}$ column and the$j^{th}$ row using $n$ lines, for each integral value of $k$ from $0$ to $n-1$ draw a line segment connecting point $p_{i\times k}$ to point $p_{(i+j)\times k}$, where any point $p_x = (\cos{2\pi \frac{x}{n}},\ \sin{2\pi \frac{x}{n}})$

The below images were generated each using $1009$ semi-transparent line segments. I choose 1009 because I wanted a prime number to minimize overlapping line segments, and because I wanted at least 1000 lines.

Anyway!!! Do the below images/shapes have a name? I've seen the top rightmost shape before in string art, and the same with some of the others. The rest are just a generalization of that process. What is this process called?

[image]

Here is a rendering with $i=20$, $j=19$, and $n=15013$

[image]

Comment: They look kind of like [rose curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)#/media/File:Rose-rhodonea-curve-7x9-chart-improved.svg).

Comment: I'd bet money that they're [epicycloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid). For example, the first two are [cardiod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) and a [nephroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid) respectively.

Comment: To the extent that these are "string art" curves, the term ["envelope"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#Envelope_of_a_family_of_curves) applies.

Comment: @Blue: Aha, "envelope" was the keyword I was looking for. See [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epicycloid.html): "Epicycloids can also be constructed by beginning with the diameter of a circle and offsetting one end by a series of steps of equal arc length along the circumference while at the same time offsetting the other end along the circumference by steps $n+1$ times as large. After traveling around the circle once, the envelope of an $n$-cusped epicycloid is produced, as illustrated above (Madachy 1979)."